# Multiple filters on a table with the ability to add more

Tags: php, jquery, html, filtering, tabular

I am in need of creating a table that will get its data from a database (this is done:) ).

The users must be able to filter the table if they want to find specific rows based on the their input.

The table will have around 33 columns which not all of them will be visible, but the user can drag and drop new columns whenever he likes. and be able to filter the table using values from these columns as well.

The table will look like this and every time the user inputs something on the top of a column then the table will get filtered based on that column. also multiple filters can be placed.

Any ***suggestions*** on how to do this? is it even possible?

[image: the table will look like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like suggest you to use http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source_chosen.html jquery plugin for datatable also it works with ajax source

Comment: thanks that worked perfeclty